# Manage sqlite on real device with eclipse

Tags: java, android, sql, eclipse, ddms

I'm using galaxy note with rooted software but I'm retying to find some way to test and manage and browse all my sqlite contents values and tables via eclipse

I have used com.questoid.sqlitebrowser_1.2.0.jar plugin but it give me disabled button in DDMS

note : I'm deploying my app on real device not emulator

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure if this gonna helps you. But, i had the same problem with questoid and the problem was that i tried to access a database file that wasn't closed by my application.

I also was using WAL Sqlite database. If you are using a WAL sqlite database and then you found 2 files with extension .shm and .wal, then your database file is not closed.